# Can't access request.json content

Tags: python, flask, axios

I am using axios to make the frontend (React) communicate with the backend (flask).
I have an issue with getting the request.json data. Here is the semple code:

`app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint
from api2.blueprints import api2
from flask_cors import CORS
app = Flask(__name__)

app.register_blueprint(api2)
CORS(app)
CORS(api2)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return '<h1>hi</h1>', 200

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

`api2/__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Blueprint

api2 = Blueprint('api2', __name__, url_prefix='/api2')

from . import some_url
```

`api2/some_url.py`:

```
from . import api2
from flask import request

@api2.before_request
def before_request():
    print(request.json)

@api2.route('/some_url')
def get_some():
    return '<h1>here is some</h1>', 200
```

here is the axios request code:

```
componentDidMount(){
        const data = {
            "project_id": "1",
            "username": "user1"
        }
        axios({url:"/some_url",data:data, 
                headers: {"ContentType": "application/json"},method:"GET"})
            .then(resp=>{
                console.log(resp);
                this.setState({sysMissions:Object.values(resp.data.data)})
            });
    }
```

So this fails so I placed a break point in the `before_request` method. When I looked at the request object fields I see the `is_json` is `True` but there was some error in the json data decoding and this white message appears when I hover over the `json` field:
[image: json decode error]

I also tried to JSON.stringify my data but that didn't work as well and also got the `is_json` field to be `False`.

There seems to be some decode error. As I see it the json data is UTF-8 encoded. Should I set axios encoding to something else?

Comment: What is the result when you remove `print(request.json)`? In a get request, this is likely empty, so the error you're getting may be caused by this. Also, double check that your get_some function is returning json - you can use `from flask import jsonify ... return jsonify({ "key": "value"})` to handle this.

Comment: @djnz
There is no problem with the `get_some` function and it returns a valid html. Also, there is no problem with adding json data to a get request. I had tried turning this into a post method and it produced the same issue.

Comment: From your above comment "and it returns a valid html" and from the error message, you are trying to call `.json()` on a content (html) that is not a valid json format.

Comment: @Nerveless_child I think you misunderstood: What I meant is that if I remove the `print(resqiest.json)` (or also the entire `before_request` method) the `get_some()` function works fine and returns valid html as exactly what it says in the return statement: `return '<h1>here is some</h1>', 200`. What I sent using axios : the `data` object mentioned in the axios request code snippet, should be a valid json.

Comment: `'<h1>here is some</h1>', 200` being returned from `get_some` is not valid json.